# xgboost properties are not working after being installed properly

Tags: python, xgboost

I've tried to install xgboost via pip, but due to some problem with the egg file, error occured. Then i tried the following:

*git clone --recursive https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost
cd xgboost; make -j4*

It was working well. Now pip says xgboost and sklearn is installed properly. However i encounter some problems when i try to repeat some basic code from different xgboost examples ( like : https://machinelearningmastery.com/develop-first-xgboost-model-python-scikit-learn/ or several other webpages)

- import xgboost as xgb
- from xgboost import *
- import sklearn as skl
- from sklearn import *
- from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

works fine (just gives back DepreciationWarning), but several attributes are not working, like:

**booster = xgb.Booster()**

gives back:

*AttributeError: module 'xgboost' has no attribute 'Booster'*

and **model = XGBClassifier()** comes with:

*NameError: name 'XGBClassifier' is not defined*

Do anyone has any idea what could be my mistake?

Comment: It is generally bad practice to use `from module import *`. Try going without the second and fourth lines and see what happens.

Comment: Thank you, i solved the problem finally by reinstalling ubuntu and python packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably using the wrong version. version 0.6.x contains the booster function but the latter (0.7.x) does not contain them anymore. It is possible to do everything from before but accessing different functions ...